# Yii 1.1 Class conflict when creating an object

Tags: php, class, yii

I am using a Yii 1.1 version in my project and I have two classes in the same name.

One class is a component and another is Controller Class. Please find the below path and code example.

protected/components/Payment.php

```
class Payment extends AppComponent {

}
```

protected/controllers/Payment.php

```
class Payment {
    public function __construct($paymentType) {
        $this->paymentType = $paymentType;
    }
}
```

protected/controllers/SiteController.php

```
require_once( $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . '/protected/controllers/Payment.php' );
$paymentInit = new Payment(PAYMENT::PAYMENT_TYPE);
```

The above code `protected/controllers/Payment.php` is not properly placed/naming in the project file path which caused the issue of the same class name as the component file `protected/components/Payment.php` which conflicts while creating an object for the class when we are calling this in `SiteController.php`.

Kindly help with this and let me know how can I get the data from `protected/controllers/Payment.php` to my `SiteController.php`

*Note: I don't want to rename the Class name because it's written by someone before. If I renamed the class name then it's working fine but it will be hugely impacted on our existing codebase.*

Comment: You need to rename this class, preferably by adding namespaces. In PHP you can't have two classes with the same name. Also `protected/controllers/Payment.php` is definitely a wrong place for such class.

Comment: @rob006 Yes, I know this is in the wrong place. But we can't move this. because this file used in other areas. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How it can be used, if it does not work? Autoload should not work for this class, unless you specify specify import path manually.

Answer (score 1):

> protected/controllers/Payment.php

Only controllers should be placed under `protected/controllers`. If Payment.php is an controller, so the name should be `PaymentController.php`.

> I don't want to rename the Class name

2 classes with same names without using namespaces is a problem.
Namespace are part of Yii2, but not scope of yii1, because Yii1 requires PHP 5.1, while namespaces are added to PHP in version 5.3.

> Kindly help with this and let me know how can I get the data from protected/controllers/Payment.php to my SiteController.php

The application bootsrap + controller + modell + view are bundled. You can not simple grab an method or class from the controller out of the bundle in order to get this working like it is in the bundle. If you like to use the code in different controllers, you should move them to an component and reference this code from both controllers.

If you only need the output of your payment controller, you also could load an render the whole action like calling the website. For this use `file_get_contents(<URL tu your payment action>)` in your `SiteController.php`